# MySQL UPDATE with Python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, sql-update

I am trying to update records from my database named Template, Table clients. I get my updated information from a Tkinter Treeview. I am updating any field except user_id which is my primary key. I get a syntax error on cur.execute(sql_command). cur is define as my cursor.

```py
# Function to Edit Record 
def edit_client():
# Update the Database
    print(user_id_box.get())
    sql_command = ("UPDATE clients SET \
        f_name = f_name_box.get(),\
        l_name = l_name_box.get(),\
        email = email_box.get(),\
        phone = phone_box.get(),\
        price = price_box.get(),\
        address = address_box.get(),\
        city = city_box.get(),\
        state = state_box.get(),\
        country = country_box.get(),\
        zipcode = zipcode_box.get() WHERE user_id = user_id_box.get()")

   # Execute the SQL command
   cur.execute(sql_command)
   # Commit the changes to the database
   mydb.commit()
   # Clear the old entry
   clear_record()
   # Refresh the Data Frame
   query_database()
```

Comment: Not an indentation error? I can see that you forgot a space every line after `sql_command`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `f_name.get()` inside a string like `"f_name = f_name.get()"` will not work.

For your case, you can use placeholder (`%s` for MySQL) in SQL statement:

```py
sql_command = f"""UPDATE clients
                  SET f_name = %s, l_name = %s,
                      email = %s, phone = %s,
                      price = %s, address = %s,
                      city = %s, state = %s,
                      country = %s, zipcode = %s
                  WHERE user_id = %s"""

cur.execute(sql_command, (f_name_box.get(), l_name_box.get(),
                          email_box.get(), phone_box.get(),
                          price_box.get(), address_box.get(),
                          city_box.get(), state_box.get(),
                          country_box.get(), zipcode_box.get(),
                          user_id_box.get()))
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use `WHERE user_id = %s` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud It is typo, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yep it works with the placeholder. Very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be using f-string and braces to properly put values inside string. Here I also used docstrings, so you don't need backslashes.

```py
def edit_client():
    print(user_id_box.get())
    sql_command = f"""UPDATE clients SET 
        f_name = {f_name_box.get()},
        l_name = {l_name_box.get()},
        email = {email_box.get()},
        phone = {phone_box.get()},
        price = {price_box.get()},
        address = {address_box.get()},
        city = {city_box.get()},
        state = {state_box.get()},
        country = {country_box.get()},
        zipcode = {zipcode_box.get()} WHERE user_id = {user_id_box.get()}"""

   cur.execute(sql_command)
   mydb.commit()
   clear_record()
   query_database()
```

**HOWEVER**
I do strongly recommend you to sanitise your inputs and pass them as arguments to executor, as SQL injections are still a thing, even if you don't care about security, you can still simply break query, by having broken inputs.

I do not know which library you utilise in order to communicate with DB, but it's documentation should cover it, if it is not from early 1970, created by some student.

Comment: Apart from SQL injection, your solution does not work if any field is a string field.  For example if `f_name` is a string field and `f_name_box.get()` returns `John`, then the final SQL will be something like `UPDATE ... SET f_name = John, ...` which is invalid. It should be like `UPDATE ... SET f_name = "John", ...`.  Placeholders should be used instead of f-string.